# std::deque and multi thread access

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

Please, help me understand this one. I am new to multi-threading programming and queueing techniques.

I currently have 2 threads working on a **same** `deque` like this: `std::deque< VideoFrame > inputQueue`. (VideoFrame is my struct of data).

And **each thread** has this pointer to that shared resource: `std::deque< VideoFrame > *p_inputQueue`.

I also made a global critical section using: `std::mutex mtxlock;`


Let say, the job of the first thread is to continuously `push_back` data to the `deque`:

```
mtxlock.lock();
p_inputQueue->push_back(frame);
mtxlock.unlock();
```

For the second thread, it has a loop to access first element of the queue, do some caculating(not changing value) and then `pop_front`. So I wonder **what is the better approach?**

**This one:**

```
mtxlock.lock();
VideoFrame *pFrame = &p_inputQueue->front();    
//A very long computing process using pointer *pFrame
p_inputQueue->pop_front();
mtxlock.unlock();
```

**Or using iterator:**

```
mtxlock.lock();
std::deque< VideoFrame >::iterator it = p_inputQueue->begin();
//A very long computing process using *it
p_inputQueue->pop_front();
mtxlock.unlock();
```

And also I wonder **do I need to lock** the whole queue like that?

---

**EDIT:**
Thank you for all answers and comments so far. I just want to make thing a little bit clear. That copy/move the element from queue to an object is not a cheap process, so I thought about using pointer/iterator instead. Sorry if haven't edited sooner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely don't want to hold the lock during processing. You have a few choices:

1. If the object is cheap to copy, make a copy of it, call `pop_front`, release the lock, then process the copy.
2. If you're using C++11 and the object is cheap to move, move it, call `pop_front`, release the lock, then process the new object.
3. Use `deque<shared_ptr<VideoFrame>>`. Copy/move the `shared_ptr` off the front, call `pop_front`, release the lock, then process the object using the copy of the `shared_ptr`.
4. Use `unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr`. Acquire the lock, move the `unique_ptr` off the front, call `pop_front`, release the lock, then process the object using the `unique_ptr` you moved to.
5. Use `deque<VideoFrame*>` and make sure to `delete` the `VideoFrame` when you're done with it.

Comment: So you mean if I use the 5th choice, I really don't need to `lock` or call `pop_front` for my queue, just `delete`?

Comment: @TrungNguyen You do need a lock to protect concurrent access to the deque, and you do need to call `pop_front` to remove the pointer from the deque. You have to avoid having one thread access the deque while another might be modifying it. The goal of all these methods is to ensure the lock is not held any longer than necessary.

Comment: If I use `deque<VideoFrame*>`, when I call `VideoFrame* pFrame = p_inputQueue->front();` and after that call `p_inputQueue->pop_front();` so `pFrame` still a valid pointer until I call `delete pFrame;`?

Comment: @TrungNguyen Yes, The `pop_front` only gets rid of  the pointer on the deque. You no longer need its value since you have a copy of it. And getting rid of a regular pointer has no effect on the thing it points to (unless it points to itself!).

Answer (score 4):

I doubt there is any significant difference between your two approaches.

One thing I would recommend (if your program logic allows it), is to take the element off the queue and unlock the queue before you begin processing. This way you don't block the other thread for an excessive amount of time. Obviously this is only possible if there are no other potential race conditions introduced by the processing logic other than the queue access itself:

```
mtxlock.lock();

//make a copy
VideoFrame frame = p_inputQueue->front();    
p_inputQueue->pop_front();
mtxlock.unlock();

//A very long computing process using object frame, after unlock
```

If the `VideoFrame` object is too heavy or otherwise impractical to copy, consider keeping a queue of pointers to them instead (i.e. `std::deque<VideoFrame*>` or even `std::deque<std::unique_ptr<VideoFrame>>`).

Comment: I would point out that @Trung Nguyen's both approaches are *wrong*, because he uses the pointer/iterator instead of making the copy, which is invalidated after `pop_front()`. While @Smeeheey's answer correctly make the copy.

Comment: @Mine - he doesn't call `pop_front()` until after he's done with his pointer/iterator

Comment: Thank you, and yes, copying the element to the object is an impractical  approach in my case. That's why I tried to use pointer or iterator. For the time locking is also one of my concerns. I really want to get the advantage of using multithread, but the process time took amount of time that even my program works like a single thread, because the first thread always waits for the second to finish its job.

Comment: In that case I strongly recommend switching your design to using a queue of pointers instead. That will solve your locking-for-the-whole-of-processing problem.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches look less than ideal to me. I would tend to prefer the simple pointer over the iterator. However using an iterator/pointer to the object you are processing while it is being stored *by value* in the *deque* is problematic.

If you store the frame objects in the *deque* by value does that mean they are cheap to copy? Can they be *moved*? If so I would be tempted to copy/move them off the *deque* before processing allowing you to free the lock sooner.

Alternately you could store *pointers* to the frames in your *deque* rather than values.

Either way the problem with your posted approach is that it is not *exception safe* if an exception occurs after you lock the *mutex* but before you unlock it the *deque* will remain locked. It also locks the *deque* for the extended processing period:

```
// not exception safe
mtxlock.lock();

// Taking the address means locking the whole queue
// until you have finished with the one element
VideoFrame* pFrame = &p_inputQueue->front();

//A very long computing process using pointer *pFrame
p_inputQueue->pop_front();

// not exception safe
mtxlock.unlock();
```

I would favor copying/moving the objects from the *deque* and using `std::lock_guard` to ensure exception safety (it will release the lock automatically if there is an exception)

```
// ready to copy/move the object by value
VideoFrame frame;

{ // start a new block for the lock

    // get a local automatic lock
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtxlock); 

    // copy/move the object out of the queue
    // so you can release the lock immediately
    frame = std::move(p_inputQueue->front());
    p_inputQueue->pop_front();

} // lock is released here

// Now it doesn't matter how long it takes
// to process the object
```

Alternatively store *pointers* in the *deque*:

```
// store pointers in the queue
VideoFrame* pFrame;

{ // start a new block for the lock

    // get a local automatic lock
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtxlock);

    // copy the pointer out of the queue
    // so you can release the lock immediately
    pFrame = p_inputQueue->front();
    p_inputQueue->pop_front();

} // lock is released here

// Now it doesn't matter how long it takes
// to process the object
```

If you decide to store pointers in your *deque* then I would suggest using a *smart pointer* such as a `std::unique_ptr`. That would be equivalent to your storing the frame by *value*:

```
// store unique pointers in the queue
std::deque<std::unique_ptr<VideoFrame>>* p_inputQueue;

// ...

std::unique_ptr<VideoFrame> pFrame;

{ // start a new block for the lock

    // get a local automatic lock
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtxlock);

    // move the unique pointer out of the queue
    // so you can release the lock immediately
    pFrame = std::move(p_inputQueue->front());
    p_inputQueue->pop_front();

} // lock is released here

// Now it doesn't matter how long it takes
// to process the object
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're actually using an iterator in the way it's intended (to iterate over a collection), your iterator method as a consumer will lock the queue until *every* element on the queue has been processed <sup>(a)</sup>. This will prevent the producer from writing new elements to the queue while that is happening.

That may or may not be a problem in a single-producer, single-consumer scenario, depending on the relative speeds of production and consumption.

By that, I mean the use of a queue is often to handle situations where production and consumption are decoupled, otherwise you could just call the consumer code directly from the producer.

For example, you may get periodic high-activity bursts on the production side which will result in many items entering the queue because the consumption side can't keep up.

In that case, the queue is used as a holding point so the consumption side can catch up during low-activity production times.

Locking the queue during consumption of all elements on it will basically halt the producer for that time, meaning that the buffering is useless.

---

It's also going to cause real issues if you switch to a multiple-consumer paradigm.

The whole point of multiple consumers is to balance the load across those multiple consumers to increase overall throughput. That's not going to happen if each consumer simply grabs the queue and processes all items on it.

At any given point of time in that situation, only one consumer will ever be active at a time.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If you're just using the iterator to get the first element, then it's possible your lock could have a finer resolution.

However, that would rather defeat the use of using an iterator in the first place so I consider that unlikely.

Comment: "Using your iterator method as a consumer will lock the queue until every element on the queue has been processed" - there is nothing in the OP's code snippet that suggests this would be the case. He locks, processes a single element, then unlocks. Where do you see the loop that consumes every element before unlocking again?

Comment: @Smeeheey, it's the fact that OP is actually *using* an iterator (regardless of the code posted). There's little point in using an iterator to just get the first element of a queue, iterators are generally meant to ... well ... iterate over a collection :-) I'll clarify my answer with that assumption.

Comment: He's specifically comparing using a pointer to the front element to using an iterator to the front element. There is nothing there about going beyond the front element.

Comment: @Smeeheey, in that case, using an iterator would be a total waste of time.